# Rename a Windows network Adapter based on Description of the adapter

Tags: windows, wifi, vpn-client

We need to rename the network adapter for a number of devices, however the adapter name can be different on different devices.
The identifier is the description of the adapter so wondering if anyone has renamed an adapter name based on the description of the apapter.

Comment: maybe would be a chance with powershell

Comment: Consider using CDNs

Answer (score 2):

A simple one-liner in Powershell.

```powershell
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceDescription -eq 'whatever' } |
  Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "MyAdapter"
```

Comment: thank you - that worked.